# How to calculate Matrix power 4 in SQL

Tags: sql, matrix

Hi I am new to SQL and know how to do matrix multiplication in SQL and I multiplied a matrix with itself to get power 2

But I can't figure out how to nest another query to get power 4

This is what I have written so far

```
%%sql
SELECT A.i AS i, A.j AS j,

(SELECT SUM(A1.val*A2.val)     
FROM A A1 CROSS JOIN A A2    
WHERE A1.i = A.i    
AND A2.j = A.j    
AND A2.i = A1.j) AS val

FROM A;
```

Any help would be very appreciated

Comment: What is the content of table A?

Comment: @Kendle A is a 3x3 matrix with schema:
int i : row index,
int j : column index, 
int val: value at position

Comment: Posting sample data from a table is usually more helpful than describing it.